# Bootstrap Dual Listbox - Both Lists Superimposed with "0 selected" in Chromium-based Mobile Browsers

Tags: chromium, bootstrap-duallistbox

I am experiencing an issue with `Bootstrap Dual Listbox` wherein both the selected and non-selected lists are superimposed with a "0 selected" message in ***Chromium-based mobile browsers***. The lists are not visible but are selectable by tapping on the down arrow on right side of the respective controls. Please note, this behavior is not observed in `Firefox` nor is it a problem in `Windows`-based `Chromium` browsers.

I have included the following screen shot for illustration purposes:

[image: Bootstrap Dual Listbox Issue]

The screen shot is taken from `Google Chrome` on a Samsung Galaxy S8+ running `Android Pie`.

I have validated that the non-selected list is refreshed and options are selectable via the down arrow on the right side of the control. Likewise, after selecting and moving an option, the option is visible in the selected list by tapping on the down arrow on the control.

My constructor for each instance of the plug-in is as follows:

```
$("#CrewMembers").bootstrapDualListbox({
    showFilterInputs: false,
    infoText: false,
    moveOnSelect: true,
    infoTextEmpty: false
});
```

I am new to `Bootstrap Dual Listbox` and I would like to continue using it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE (7/23/2020):**

I replaced the `Bootstrap Dual Listbox` plug-in with an equivalent jQuery/Javascript plug-in (`jQuery Dualselect`) and got the same result.  ***This issue appears to reside with Chromium and not the plug-ins.***

An issue has been submitted to the Chromium development team.